# Storing chat messages with an irc bot

Tags: message, store, bots, irc

I am trying to code a simple irc bot that detects if a word is inside a chat message and then saves that message to a file. I have the correct 'on text' event set up, but I don't know how to access the message that was sent so I can save it.

```
on *:TEXT:*txt*:#: 
{
   var %message $msg
   writeini Log.ini Message value %message
}
```

$msg is clearly wrong. Is there an identifier to have my bot access the messages in the chat, or is there a completely different way to do this? I can't seem to find anything online about this either.

Comment: What have you written this in? How are you connecting the bot to irc? How is $msg clearly wrong?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. The identifier I was looking or was '$1-'. I'm coding in the script editor of mIRC, and $msg is wrong because there is no such thing as the identifier '$msg'. Just a value I used to try and make the question more clear